# Measurability of a Borel function

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

I need some help on the following proof.
The claim is: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f \in B(\mathbb{R}^k)/B(\mathbb{R})$. i.e. Borel measurable.  Let $X_1$,...,$X_k$ be  random variables on $(\Omega,B)$. Then $f(X_1,...,X_k) \in \sigma(X_1,....X_k)$.

I got the idea for one-dimensional case (i.e. when $k=1$) using the principles of inverse of a composition mapping, i.e., $(f\circ X)^{-1}$=$X^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$ and since $f$ is Borel function so is $f^{-1}$. But now for the multidimensional case i got little lost how do i handle the inverse mapping and relating to sigma field generated by a collection of r.v's. Can anyone guide me a bit? How to express the $\sigma(X_1,....,X_k)$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\omega \mapsto(X_1, X_2, \cdots X_n)$ is a measurable function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  It is, more strongly, also $\sigma(X_1, X_2, \cdots X_n)$-measurable.  Since $f$ is measurable, the composition $f(X_1, X_2, \cdots X_n)$ is $\sigma(X_1, X_2, \cdots X_n)$-measurable.

Comment: Could you please explain the last part a bit why the composition is $\sigma(X_1,...X_k)$ measurable?

Comment: A composition of measurable functions is measurable. Think about the definition of product measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$